# Telerik RadCombobox not keeping state when using client side requestItems() to load

Tags: telerik, client-side, radcombobox

I'm using the Telerik RadComboBox control. I have two related combos and when the user selects a value in the first one I filter the second one.

I use the code below to achieve this:

```
localeCombo = $find("<%= ddlLocale.ClientID %>");
localeCombo.requestItems(item.get_value(), false);
```

This works totally fine, but when I do a postback my filtered combo resets to the original non filtered list, although all other controls retain their state. I assume this is because the server side list of items is not being updated when I use the client side callback requestItems() function.

Is this the case? Is there a simple way around this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, most probably your suggestion is true. You may try keeping the second filtered combo value in session or cache storage and then restore it from there on postback - at least this is what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with RadComboBox. I opened a ticket.

Comment: Got response from Telerik. Turns out this is not a bug but a feature. "The experienced behavior is not a bug, but a default one when using load on demand mechanism. In such cases the items of the RadComboBox are not persisted on the server-side and you could access only the SelectedValue or Text of the control.

Please refer to the following help article discussing this behavior."