# Update a controls viewstate on an AJAX callback

Tags: ajax, telerik, radcombobox

I update a rad combo control using telerik calllback method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211797/telerik-radcombobox-not-keeping-state-when-using-client-side-requestitems-to-lo)

The items in the list are changed on the callback and I want to maintain this filtered list after the postback.

Is it possible to update the viewstate in the server side method? I think if I can access this i can then update both my list of items on the client and the server.. allow my drop down list to survive a postback

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

littleschris, you do not need to update the combobox viewstate but rather to store it selected value and then recover it after postback. Hope my explanation is useful.

Dick

Comment: Thanks Dick. The items in the list are changed on the callback and I want to maintain this filtered list after the postback..... selected value isn't what I'm trying to maintain.. I've updated my question.